# ¿Cuándo se introdujo "masacre" en el castellano? ¿Qué termino se utilizaba antes?

Tags: etimología, historia, extranjerismos

Estaba leyendo hace poco un libro sobre historias de la Guerra Civil española escrito en 1937: *A sangre y fuego. Héroes, bestias y mártires de España*, de Manuel Chaves Nogales.

En él hay un capítulo que narra los bombardeos sobre la población de Madrid y la gran cantidad de muertos que producían. Me resultó curioso que el título de esta parte fuera *Massacre*, con cursiva y dos eses. Es decir, tomándolo directamente como palabra extranjera, en particular del francés *massacre* ([de posible origen latino](https://www.etymonline.com/word/massacre)).

En el DLE lo definen así:

> [**masacre**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWHSjcM)
>   `Del fr. massacre.`
>
> 1. f. Matanza de personas, por lo general indefensas, producida por ataque armado o causa parecida.

Había oído con frecuencia relativa la palabra *masacre*, por lo que me sorprendió descubrir que hace relativamente tan poco tiempo que se incorporó al castellano. Mirando en el Mapa de diccionarios veo que no es hasta 1992 que se incluye (la anterior es 1925).

Así pues, la pregunta es: ¿en qué momento se introdujo? Y teniendo en cuenta que de masacres el mundo ya estaba lleno por aquel entonces, ¿qué término era el más común para referirse a ellas anteriormente?

Comment: No veo problema con usar la palabra *matanza* en lugar de *masacre* en la mayoría de los casos. Esta última tiene un significado más restringido y, por tanto, da un matiz adicional, pero no introduce un concepto nuevo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el NTLLE se recoge su uso desde la edición de 1984 del DLE, con la definición de "matanza de personas por lo general indefensas". Sin embargo, si buscamos *massacre* con las dos *s* se encuentran un par de referencias: una en el Minsheu de 1617 y otra en el Stevens de 1706, que traduce la palabra com "slaughter", lo que no deja lugar a dudas de su significado.

Sin embargo, no encuentro casos de *massacre* en textos del CORDE allá por los siglos XVII o XVIII. Para el caso de *masacre*, el texto más antiguo es precisamente de 1937, como tu ejemplo:

> *En holocausto sagrado,
>
>   ante la masacre infecta
>
>   del fascismo, entregaré
>
>   mi sangre de gotas férvidas.*
>
> Miguel Hernández, "Pastor de la muerte. Drama en cuatro actos", 1937 (España).

Usando NGram de momento el texto más antiguo que usa *masacre* es de 1920, aunque hay algunos anteriores que hacen mención al río Masacre.

Como ya apunta Gorpik, su sustituto es *matanza*, documentada desde el Diccionario de Autoridades y encontrada en textos de hasta el siglo XIII, dado que su significado carece de ese matiz de indefensión de la víctima, aunque también se podía usar con ese sentido, como se ve en este ejemplo que aparece en el citado diccionario:

> Mandó el Padre Joseph a los Indios, que no prosiguiessen la *matanza* de los monos, sino que se contentassen con gozar del ridiculo espectaculo que hacian.

Ejemplo anterior:

> *E pues este rrey tan poderoso vio andar a don Hector en la batalla faziendo muy grand matanza [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Historia troyana en prosa y verso", c1270 (España).