# What is the difference between "matanza" and "masacre"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

I'm interested in translating the English word "massacre." I had always thought that the best translation was "matanza" - learned mainly from growing up in Florida and visiting Fort Matanzas National Monument in St. Augustine:

https://www.nps.gov/foma/index.htm

But this Spanish Wikipedia article about the shooting of settlers in Puerto Montt, Chile refers to "La masacre de Puerto Montt":

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masacre_de_Puerto_Montt

What's the difference between the two? Is it a regional difference, maybe Chilean Spanish vs. Castilian Spanish? Or is it a contextual difference, or does it indicate the speaker's attitude toward the events? What would be the preferred word in modern Spanish?

Comment: Note that _masacre_ comes from French _massacre_ and was introduced late in the XX century in the Spanish dictionary. See [¿Cuándo se introdujo “masacre” en el castellano? ¿Qué termino se utilizaba antes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26773/1674).

Comment: matanza is killing. masacre is a masacre.

Comment: Besides the very good points made in the answers, *masacre* has an emotional connotation that *matanza* doesn't. Shooting a group of unarmed people in cold blood is a *masacre* and calling it like that emphasizes the inhumanity of the action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is that you could make a *Matanza* against humans or against pigs, but a *Matanza* of humans, could be in a battle, in the middle of a war. A *Masacre*, technically is against civil people, or unarmed people.

For example, a *matanza* could happen when an army destroys another... a *masacre* when an army, or an illegal armed group, attack some village, or some protest march and kill some people.

The dictionary says (if you understands some Spanish, it would help):

> [Matanza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OacptxR)
>    Mortandad de personas ejecutada en una batalla, un asalto, etc.
>
> [Masacre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWHSjcM)
>   Matanza de personas, por lo general indefensas, producida por ataque armado o causa parecida

Comment: Esto es perfecto, exactamente lo que quería saber. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Una matanza de [animales o personas]= killing, the verb is matar.

Una masacre de [animales o personas]=masacre, the verb is masacrar

Matanza is to killing as masacre is to massacre.